# Qué modulo de xarray dataset puedo usar que sea equivalente a np.trim_zeros?

Tags: python, array, numpy

Tengo un xarray dataset al que le quiero aplicar np.trim_zeros con trim= 'b' pero no me sirve colocar el xarray dataset con .value porque no se le puede aplicar len. Alguien conoce alguna forma de usar np.trim_zeros con xarray dataset?